# Cannot find LDAP 5.2 dictionary file

Tags: ldap

We have LDAP 5.2 running so that it checks your password against a dictionary file when you change your password.  Even when doing this from the LDAP GUI it responds with an error about the password being found in the dictionary.

We need to add some words to this list, but cannot find it anywhere. Any ideas on how we can see what word file is being used to check passwords against?

Thanks.

Note: We are using PAM on the clients, but cracklib is not configured on them. We are fairly certain the check is being made at the server and not the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.2 doesn't do dictionary password checks (which we knew, and confused that ours does) but it turns out we have a plugin installed that does this for us.

Updating the list did not work because the word list is only read when LDAP starts, so we had to restart the slapd process to get it to read the changes we made.

Everything works now.